# Columns in Table not aligned properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have this html styled with bootstrap. My problem is that the row inside `thead` is not aligned with the row inside `tbody` (see the jsfiddle link to see an example of what's happening):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th class="search" scope="col">nome</th>
      <th scope="col">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="table-body" style="display: block;" data-json="/categoria/list.json">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>hum</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group" id="buttons" role="group" aria-label="comandos">
          <button sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'atualiza_categoria')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="update" th:attr="data-url=@{/categoria/update}" onclick="open_tab(this)">
            edit
          </button>
          <button sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_categoria')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="delete" th:attr="data-url=@{/categoria/delete}" onclick="open_tab(this)">
            del
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="table-search" style="display: none;" data-json="/categoria/search.json"></tbody>
</table>
```

this code is based on the first example available here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/. I tried change the line:

```
<th scope="row">1</th>
```

inside `tbody` to:

```
<td scope="row">1</td>
```

but the same issue occurs.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/0gdtf7qy/

Anyone can tell how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `tbody` `display: block;`. `tbody` `display` property will be `table-row-group`.

So removed `style="display: block;"` from `tbody` tag. Check here [working example](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/RwNGLjY)

Answer (score 1):

Remove **display: block;** css property from tbody tag

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th class="search" scope="col">nome</th>
      <th scope="col">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="table-body"  data-json="/categoria/list.json">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>hum</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group" id="buttons" role="group" aria-label="comandos">
          <button sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'atualiza_categoria')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="update" th:attr="data-url=@{/categoria/update}" onclick="open_tab(this)">
            edit
          </button>
          <button sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_categoria')" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="delete" th:attr="data-url=@{/categoria/delete}" onclick="open_tab(this)">
            del
          </button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="table-search" style="display: none;" data-json="/categoria/search.json"></tbody>
</table>
```